# How to refer javafx from command line?

Tags: java, command-line, javafx, classpath

I am using some classes from javafx library (these are observable collections). I can't include `jfxrt.jar` into my distribution, since it is java version dependent and I don't know which java my program will run on.

How to accomplish?

**UPDATE**

I put `jfxrt.jar` in `lib` subdirectory of the programm directory and the following command does not work

```
java -classpath ./lib/jfxrt.jar -jar MyProgram.jar
```

Why?

**UPDATE 2**

This was also does not work

```
java -cp MyProgram.jar;./lib/* MyClass
```

Comment: Actually **you can** include jfxrt.jar.  It will run on most machines (especially if you are just using a few classes as mentioned). Plus you can always go to native packaging.

Comment: JRE distribution has multiple jars inside. How are they used without reference, for example: alt-rt.jar  charsets.jar  deploy.jar  javaws.jar  jce.jar  jfr.jar  jfxrt.jar  jsse.jar  management-agent.jar  plugin.jar  resources.jar  rt.jar

Comment: I included the jfxrt from java 8 into a windows xp with java 7 and it ran just fine. And again, if you are afraid **use native packaging**.

Comment: What is native packaging, sorry?

Comment: Look [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_for_javafx). Native packaging includes a full JRE to run in any operating system and with system binaries.

Comment: Wow, it's hot! Would like to try other ways first.

Comment: Note the [Java launcher documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html): "When you use the `-jar` option, the specified JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other class path settings are ignored."

Answer (score 0):

In your jar `META-INF` folder create a `MANIFEST.MF` file with this contents:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: . /lib/jfxrt.jar
Main-Class: package.MyClass
```

or put this in `.classpath` the root of the jar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/lib/jfxrt.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

Then try to launch it again